# Why is decoherence considered to be a 'trick' used for practical purposes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

As I understand, decoherence consists of making the observation that when we trace out the environment from the overall density matrix of the system, we get von Neumann's projection postulate state with classical amplitudes. Furthermore, we know that we can always embed a local irreversible process in a global reversible one.

I want to add that I am not looking for more technical objections against decoherence theory, I just want to know why it has the FAPP tag against it, and what more is expected from it by physicists.

Comment: Related: [What are the strongest objections to be made against decoherence as an explanation of “collapse?”](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373905) and [Decoherence. Does it solve the measurement problem? Is it discontinuous? When does it occur?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295527)

Comment: Some things to think about: (1) Tracing out the environment is equivalent to ignoring the environment's observables. The projection postulate is how we tell the theory which outcome actually occurred in a measurement. How could the former replace the latter? (2) To use quantum theory correctly, we need to know when a measurement has occurred and what observable has been measured. How does the theory tell us that? How would the theory tell us which part of the system to call the "environment"? And what's the precise definition of "measurement" anyway? (What's the precise definition of "river"?)